# Read an integer from a .txt file opened from command line

Tags: c, input

I need to read an integer from a .txt file opened from command line, like this:

```
myprogram < input.txt
```

I can't use scanf as it won't read anything, nor fscanf because I'm not opening the file in the program. gets works for the string lines in the file, but there's nothing like "getint" to read the integer line.

That's what my file looks like:

```
5     //number of following words
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
```

Comment: Can you show your program that includes `scanf()` and say why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

The `<` redirect notation means that the contents of `input.txt` will be redirected to the standard input of your program. This means that you should be able to use `scanf()` to read the file contents (or any other function that reads from standard input).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%*[^\n]");//skip comment
    char word[n][16];
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < n; ++i){
        scanf("%15s", word[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0;i < n; ++i){
        printf("%s\n", word[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```